# Simple Code: JavaScript, Uncaught ReferenceError: (x) is not defined

Tags: javascript, gyroscope, defined

I am trying to run this code, this is a code when I choose some information in the gyro and then put it on the console, but the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Gyroscope is not defined

is disrupting my project

Trying run various times, but this problem always appears.

```
function consol() {

        navigator.permissions.query({name:'gyroscope'}).then(function(result) {
         });

    }

    function le(){
        let gyroscope = new Gyroscope({frequency: 60});

        gyroscope.addEventListener('reading', e => {
          console.log("Angular velocity along the X-axis " + gyroscope.x);
          console.log("Angular velocity along the Y-axis " + gyroscope.y);
          console.log("Angular velocity along the Z-axis " + gyroscope.z);
        });
        gyroscope.start();
    }
```

I want that the information appears in console log, but this error appears:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Gyroscope is not defined

Comment: Sounds like you never defined `Gyroscope`

Comment: how i fix this? when i defined, appears other error

Comment: You *haven't* defined `Gyroscope`, that's the problem. What are you expecting that variable name to refer to?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I suspect the web api [Gyroscope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gyroscope).

Comment: yes yes, but i defined Gyroscope and appers other error,I think I'm setting it the wrong way.

Comment: `but i defined Gyroscope` - how did you do that?

Comment: If you *are* explicitly defining Gyroscope somewhere, can you post the code that does that?

Comment: The code is this, how I defined `Gyroscope`?

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta you need to read about feature detection of the [sensor api here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Sensor_APIs). You can’t just assume it will be available.

Comment: What browser are you using? The feature may not exist in the browser/device.

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta ```Gyroscope``` is a built in tool that should be defined by the browser (unless the device has no gyroscope). You defined a variable ```gyroscope```. Javascript is case sensitive when it comes to variable names, so you never defined ```Gyroscope```.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in secure context (i.e. https), as precised in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Sensor_APIs) or navigator won't allow access to device's sensors for security and privacy reasons.